# How to detect leaving a domain with a chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

On a Chrome extension, I want to run some code when a user navigates **away** from, or closes a tab with, a URL of a certain domain (e.g. "google.com").

I've tried [webNavigation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation), but it fires also when a page is prerendered by Chrome. On the other hand [onUpdated](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#event-onUpdated) does not provide the previous URL as far as I can see. onBeforeUnload would not show the next URL being navigated to.

I guess I can use a mix of those, but I'm hoping for a simpler solution.
Does anyone know how to do that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you ever get at the bottom of this one @ronme?

Answer (score 1):

I'll just give a broad method of how I'd do it, but can go into more detail if you need.

I would:

1. use a [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) which [matches](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns) on the pattern of your domain (this way you can get a more broad selection of urls in your domain).
2. <strike>use `onUpdated` as you have mentioned, but in your content script. this way, it will only check for `onUpdated` when you are in the correct domain.</strike> ... The `tabs` API is not available in content scripts as user Xan has commented. Instead, you can inject javascript into the matching webpages and look into a javascript-based solution, or use [message passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) to a background page (which does have access to `chrome.tabs`) to signify that there is a match.
3. going further with `chrome.tabs`, you can look into [onUpdated](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#event-onUpdated), [onSelectionChanged](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#event-onSelectionChanged), and [onRemoved](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#event-onRemoved), for when the tab is navigated away from or closed, and more events [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs).

Comment: (`tabs`.)`onUpdated` is not available in content scripts; `tabs` API is only for extension pages.

Comment: Thank you Noam. I've done #1 and #2, it's #3 that seems tricky, esp. because of prerendering. The tab ids can sometime change "under my feet" and it seems I have to maintain a data structure to follow the ids. I wondered if there is a simpler solution.

Comment: np, how come you're tracking the ids of the tabs?

Comment: i see that the tab ids are sometimes changing. i'm attributing it to the prerendering mechanism, which then, AFAIU, susbstitutes  the prerendered tab with the existing tab.

Comment: @ronme the goal of this solution, if successful, would be to eliminate the need to keep track of your tabs. You could instead run some code to listen for updates or other events on **only** the tabs that match your desired url pattern

Comment: I see what you mean with the prerendering issues, so you might have to add code to check for special cases for events from the tab api such as `onUpdate` (for example, id changed but not url). Looks like javascript injection might be the easiest solution to this

Comment: yes, thanks @NoamHacker. Let's see if anyone comes up with any simpler solution we may have missed.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test it but I believe something like this could work:

```
//check if the tab that was just closed had a certain url
chrome.tabs.onRemoved.addListener(function(tabId, removeInfo) {
   chrome.tabs.get(tabId, function(tab) {
      if (tab.url.indexOf("google.com") >= 0) {
         //do stuff
      }
   });
});
```

To check when the user navigates away. You could either keep track of what each tab's url is and act on that, or inject a content script on every page that would do something like this:

```
   if (document.referrer.indexOf("google.com") >= 0) {
      //do stuff
   }
```

Comment: Thanks, but the first snippet would work only on when a tab is closed, not navigated away from.
The second would work only if the original page wasn't HTTPS which in my case is.. :(

Comment: @ronme you mentioned that it should also trigger when you close the tab. I'm not sure I understand the problem with the second snippet though. It should work independently of the protocol

Comment: that snippet would certainly work closing tabs, but the harder part for me was to catch navigating *away* from the domain, so the snippet only addresses the easier part of the problem.
As for referrer - please see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer#cite_note-10 .